# GNUCash Totals On Expense Chart

Tags: gnucash

Is there anyway of getting the totals of each bar in the Expense Cart in GNUcash?

Each bar is broken up into different accounts by color, see screen shot below, and you can get the numbers for each account with a mouse hover but the sum of all the accounts is missing. You can get a estimate of the total by looking at the scale on the left but I need the exact number.
I can get that number by manually adding all the account amounts but that's shouldn't  be necessary.

[Snap shot of the Expense Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvUdS.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can go to Options, Display tab, check Show table, and press OK.

Underneath the chart a table will appear that will contain totals.